# Node.js Express JS - Could not find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, express, npm

Ive allready read 3-4 topics on this here at stackoverflow, but i simply cant seem to run my node.

I Try to run:

```
node app.js local
```

and it returns:

```
Error: Cannot find module './config'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/larsfalcon/Documents/lkrieger/git/testinggrounds/app.js:2:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Before i run this command i do:

```
npm i
```

And it installs my packages, i can physicaly see in my node_modules that express is there, but even if i try run express in the CLI it says its not a bash so i assume its not installed somehow still?

here is a review of my 2 app.js and index.js files that i need to run my node.

App.js

```
var config = require('./config')();
http.createServer(app).listen(config.port, function(){
     console.log('Express server listening on port ' + config.port);
    });
```

index.js

```
    var config = {
    local: {
        mode: 'local',
        port: 3000
    },
    staging: {
        mode: 'staging',
        port: 4000
    },
    production: {
        mode: 'production',
        port: 5000
    }
}
module.exports = function(mode) {
    return config[mode || process.argv[2] || 'local'] || config.local;
}
```

What should i do?

Comment: Where are your `require` statements?

Comment: In app.js Updatede width require statement.

Sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So that means that there is no `config.js` in the same folder as the `app.js`.

**UPDATE:** you'll want `require('./config/config')`.

Comment: Could you try update the post, i forgot to add the require in app.js

Comment: @Nopzen where is your `config.js` located?

Comment: In the /config next to the app.js file And its called index.js

Comment: Still runs same error, renamede my index.js file (config file) to config.js and did this:

var config = require('./config/config.js')();

http.createServer(app).listen(config.port, function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + config.port);
});

Comment: @Nopzen you said the `config.js` is in a `config` folder right?

Comment: My folder structure is like this

index.html
app.js
config
 - config.js

Comment: @Nopzen please see my edit; I didn't mean to include the extension.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61187/discussion-between-nopzen-and-michael-perrenoud).